# Can't run mongod as a service without root

Tags: mongodb, centos

So I'm running on CentOS 7 and just installed mongod 4.2.6 with a non-root user. Mongod runs fine with the default db path /var/lib/mongo, but I want to db path to /data/mongo, so I edit the dbpath parameter in /etc/mongod.conf to /data/mongo. I also run `sudo chown mongod:mongodb /data/mongo` to change permission. But when I restart the service, mongod crashed with the error `exception in initAndListen: Location28596: Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /data/mongo: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/data/mongo/mongod.lock", terminating`. I also tried granting mongod `chmod 777` but still it has the same issue. The only way that gets mongod to run normally is with me manually running the command `sudo mongod --dbpath /data/mongo`, which is not the preferred way. How can I get mongod to run as a service normally?

Answer (score 0):

Try chmod 755 /data.
The permission must be drwxr-xr-x